# Calling a function by a second name (homework)

Tags: linux, scripting, filenames, hard-link

I'm writing a function called `restore` that will copy a file from a backup directory to the current directory. I now need to create a hard link to restore so that it can be called as `purge`. How would I implement it so that I could use the `if` statement `if [ "$0" = "purge" ]` for when restore is called as purge?

Here is my code, although I will shorten it since I have tested it (it works):

```
restore(){
if [ "$1" = "-p" ] || [ "$0" = "purge" ]; then
while [ ! ]
    do
    #Purge code, etc...
    done


elif [ "$1" != "-p" ]; then
select fname in $(find /$HOME/Backup -name "$1*" | sed 's!.*/!!' | sed 's!$1!!') quit
        do
             #If restore is called with an argument code...
        done

local newfname=$(echo "$fname"|sed -E 's/[0-9]{11}$//')
cp -i "/$HOME/Backup/$fname" "$newfname"
exit 0
fi

while [ ! ]
do
fname=""
select fname in $(ls /$HOME/Backup) quit
        do
            #Restore with no arguments code...
        done

local newfname=$(echo "$fname"|sed -E 's/[0-9]{11}$//')
cp -i "/$HOME/Backup/$fname" "$newfname"
done
}
```

Calling restore with the `-p` option is the same as invoking restore as purge. So how would I implement the code so that restore can be invoked by using purge?

It is supposed to be a script rather than a function. I made a hard link to `Restore.sh` named `Purge.sh`, but when I call it using ./Purge.sh it still runs the standard Restore code. How can I determine if Restore is called by the hard link file?

Comment: `$0` wont work as that will just refer to your shell I believe.  `FUNCNAME` is  closer to what you need but I just tested it and if I create an alias to my function and call it by the alias, this will still display the function name.

Comment: You don't make hard links to a function, you make hard links to a _file_. A file can contain a compiled binary executable, or ... (what else?) Also, see [BashPitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (Yours has `select`, the article has `for`. It doesn't matter.)

Comment: It may be best to make this a script rather than function, add it to your `PATH` and then create a symlink to it in your PATH that is labeled `purge`.

Comment: About your edit: If it is a script and you have made hard links, you need to compare `$0` with "./Purge.sh" to make it work, not "Purge". You also need to consider many other possible ways of invoking your script `Purge.sh`. So generally I won't suggest you compare `$0` with anything and use some other workarounds.

Comment: @ilkkachu It can also contain a script.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, or pattern match against `*Purge.sh`. I think that's the reason `/bin/gunzip` is a script instead of a symlink in current systems. But if this was homework and checking the name was a requirement, well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the hard link to the `restore.sh`:

```
ln restore.sh link_to_restore.sh
```

The content of the `restore.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$0" = "./link_to_restore.sh" ]; then
    echo foo
elif [ "$0" = "./restore.sh" ]; then
    echo bar
fi
```

#### Testing

```
$ ./restore.sh 
bar
$ ./link_to_restore.sh 
foo
```

Comment: This won't work if I call the script using an absolute path (`/path/to/restore.sh`)

Comment: You can check whether it actually matches using a regular expression, e.g. `*\/restore\.sh`.

Comment: it would be better checking `if [ "${0##*/}" = "purge" ]` i.e. remove all content up to (and including) the last slash, so you compare with only the filename and discard the path in the comparison.

Answer (score 8):

Would this be cheating?  In your restore script you still have your `-p` logic and then you create a separate purge function as follows:

```
purge () { /path/to/restore.sh -p "$@"; }
```

In your restore script you should take the function wrapper of it out or I believe it will essentially just be sourced and not executed.